# Error while LDAP authenication in moodle 3.3.2

Tags: moodle

I have regularly received an issue while authenticating LDAP Server in Moodle 3.3.2.
I used centos 7 (vm) and install moodle successfully on it.
When binding LDAP authentication there is an issue while login from ad user account.

```
LDAP-module cannot connect to any servers: Server: 'IP of AD server', Connection: 'Resource id #86', Bind result: ''
```

Note: I used Distinguish name and contexts (copying dn through ldap.exe from my local computer). 
What is the meaning of display Resource Id #86' sometime it gives Resource Id #87??
Any help would be appreciate.

Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ldap server must be accessible to your moodle application server. You must check if  both the server communicating properly.
Also you can add the logs for each events to check exact issue.

Comment: how to check? can you provide some details to check for the connection between LDAP server and Moodle?

Answer (score 0):

You can telnet from your moodle application server to ldap server
Command:

telnet hostip 389

Use 636 if you are using secure port.

Note that IT can block the telnet on perticular ldap server.

Also you can log the error using below php code

echo ldap_err2str( ldap_errno());

This will return last error.

Please let me know if it helps you. Thanks

Comment: Yeah I got it. My LDAP server did not communicating with Moodle thats why it throws error. But after configuring LDAP authentication setting in my centos then it successfully login. Thanks for the info.